# SSL certificate HTTPS redirect disable via Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

So it redirects to https but as I don't have SSL certificate anymore it needs to be disabled, tried to remove the Force SSL part didn't do anything same for the force web www didn't do any change either

another thing is when I go to my site it automatically adds www. twice so wwww.www.(domainname)

here's the `htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Your document HTML
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

### Force web (www) on all URLs

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

### Force SSL (https) on all URLs

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

### Remove trailing slash from all URLs

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
    RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

    RewriteRule ^buy-([a-z0-9-]+)$ buy.php?game=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Redirect proper URL to SEO-friendly for buy.php

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} buy\.php\?game=([a-z0-9-]+)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ buy-%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally link SEO-friendly with proper URL for buy.php

    RewriteRule ^buy-([a-z0-9-]+)$ buy.php?game=$1 [L]

# Redirect proper URL to SEO-friendly for sell.php

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} sell\.php\?game=([a-z0-9-]+)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ sell-%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally link SEO-friendly with proper URL for sell.php

    RewriteRule ^sell-([a-z0-9-]+)$ sell.php?game=$1 [L]

# Redirect proper URL to SEO-friendly for testimonials.php (with pages)

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} testimonials\.php\?page=([0-9-]+)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ testimonials/%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally link SEO-friendly with proper URL for testimonials.php (with pages)

    RewriteRule ^testimonials/([0-9-]+)$ testimonials.php?page=$1 [L]


# Redirect proper URL to SEO-friendly for recover.php (with code)

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} recover\.php\?code=([a-z0-9-]+)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ recover/%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally link SEO-friendly with proper URL for recover.php (with pages)

    RewriteRule ^recover/([a-z0-9-]+)$ recover.php?code=$1 [L]


# Redirect proper URL to SEO-friendly for index.php (with order ID)

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php\?order=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ o/%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally link SEO-friendly with proper URL for index.php (with order ID)

    RewriteRule ^o/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?order=$1 [L]




# Redirect proper URL to SEO-friendly for any standard page

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(account|testimonials|contact|privacy|terms|cart|recover|faq|login|register|banned)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally link SEO-friendly with proper URL for any standard page

    RewriteRule ^(account|testimonials|contact|privacy|terms|cart|recover|faq|login|register|banned)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that you had a 301 redirect from http to https in your configuration. Simply removing this redirect and retrying will not help since 301 is the code for a **permanent** redirect which means that the browser will remember this redirect, i.e. it will visit `https://` instead of `http://` since the cached redirect says so and will not even try to visit `http://`.

To fix this you need to have both the redirect removed and the browser cache cleared - and then can you retry. And yes, this affects every client which has visited your site. Since you cannot clear the browser cache from every client you better install a new certificate. Once you have one you can redirect all users from `https://` to `http://` and after a while most browsers should have gotten the message that `http://` is the way to go so that you can remove the redirect and the certificate. Or even better, just stay with `https://`  - there are CA like Let's Encrypt which provide you with free certificates.